# Cosine similarity output different scipy vs sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I'm sure I'm overlooking something but why are these outputs different?

**scikit learn**

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
cosine_similarity([[3,5,1]],[[1,2,3]])

### output `array([[0.72280632]])`
```

**scipy**

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
cosine([3,5,1],[1,2,3])

### output 0.27719367767579906
```

Why aren't these the same? From my calculations, it doesn't seem that it's the difference between using the L1 or L2 norm in the denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions for cosine distance that they use are different.

The docstring for `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` says:

> Compute cosine similarity between samples in X and Y. Cosine similarity, or the cosine kernel, computes similarity as the normalized dot product of X and Y:
>
> $cosine(X, Y) = < X, Y > / (||X|| * ||Y||)$

While `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` says:

> The Cosine distance between X and Y, is defined as
>
> $cosine(X, Y) = 1 - < X, Y > / (||X|| * ||Y||)$.

where $< X, Y >$ is the dot product between $X$ and $Y$ and $||X||$ is the L2 norm.

(I changed the doc strings a little to use the same variable names and mathematical conventions for an easier comparison.)

Basically, you have `1 - cosine_sklearn = cosine_scipy`.

Comment: It could be better if you can fix the math formula. Nice answer!

Comment: Did you mean <X, Y> not showing up? I fixed that (I suppose the markdown processor recognized it as an HTML tag so it didn't show?). I can't make $X$ actually look like LaTeX on this site, though.

Comment: It says you can insert an image using a third party service: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76902/how-can-i-write-math-formula-in-a-post

Comment: Does that mean that sklearn is a measure of similarity and scipy is a measure of dissimilarity?

Comment: I didn't really think about this, but yes, the names tell you what they're doing: in `sklearn` you have cosine *similarity* but in scipy there's cosine *distance*. So if $X = Y$ then the similarity is 1 but the distance is 0.